# Overridable config on client side in custom npm package

Tags: npm, webpack, config

I'm trying to author an NPM package where several functions use the application configuration, like:

```
export const getCountries = () => {
  logger.log("getCountries requested", config.LOG_TARGET);
  return axios.get(`${config.API_BASE_URL}/countries`);
}
```

I want these configuration values to be definable in the project using my npm package (not in the NPM package directly).

I guess this is a fairly common use-case, but I have yet to find a good article on what is the best or most common way to do this.

I guess something like this could work:

```
// config.js
const defaultConfig = {
  KEY1: "something",
  KEY2: "something else"
}

let config = defaultConfig;

export const getConfig = () => config;
export const setConfig = (newConfig) => {
  config = { ...defaultConfig, ...newConfig };
};
```

Then I would be able to use it in the end-user project like:

```
import { setConfig } from 'mypackage/config';
setConfig({ KEY1: "specific value" });
```

And use it in the NPM package like:

```
import { getConfig } from './config';
const config = getConfig();
```

Is there any potential gotchas doing this? Am I trying to reinvent the wheel? Is there something standard I could use?

I would also like to be able to use this in a Webpack environment, but I guess `webpack.DefinePlugin` will be enough for differentiating between dev and prod builds.